# Reclaiming Unallocated Free Space that might Have Gone to Recovery Partition?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, disk-space

So, I have a pretty grave problem that I really need help with.  Earlier today, I decided to remove my old and buggy bootcamp partition and reinstall windows.  Problem was, bootcamp assistant didn't allow me to pick the same size as I previously had, so I decided to try to forcibly resize the Mac partition using `diskutil resizevolume` and then format the unallocated space into FAT32.

That's when my real problem started.  I was unable to use disk utility to convert that unallocated space afterwards, and a few boots later, I even think that the recovery partition seems to have taken the unallocated space for itself.

This is my main partition, for reference:

[image: My main partition]

And this is what `diskutil list` shows:

[image: closer look]

So my question now is this: how do I return things to normal on my hd and reclaim all the space for the main partition?  Do I have to delete the Recovery HD partition and reinstall it afterwards?  Or am I making a mistake and the space is still somehow unallocated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow merged disk0s3 and disk0s4 (the Windows partition) to one big recovery partition - consequently there is no unallocated disk space. With your published commands this shouldn't have happened though.

The fastest way to get a default partition scheme is to merge disk0s2 with disk0s3 and later recreate Recovery HD with a tool like [Recovery Partition Creator](http://musings.silvertooth.us/downloads-2/).

The merge command is:

```
diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ "Macintosh HD" disk0s2 disk0s3
```

The command will merge *Macintosh HD* and *Recovery HD* to one big *Macintosh HD* while retaining the content of your main system volume.

Comment: This did it for me, thanks a lot for your answer!  So rarely in my case does a simple, single terminal command solve my problems, so again thanks for the help.